# Is the function $e^{-Bx^2}$ a contraction on $\mathbb{R}$? ($B>0$)

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions

The tittle says it all. I think it's true, and I tried to prove it by showing that the derivative of this function: $-2Bxe^{-Bx^2}$ is bounded from above with a bound less than 1, in order to do that, I tried to use Taylor series of $e^{-Bx^2}$, but it seems that leads nowhere. Any suggestion?

Here $B>0$ is a real number and we consider the euclidean norm.

Comment: So is B and x real numbers or matrices?

Comment: Also depends what norm you use.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add more details.

Comment: Hint: $x^2$ is always positive and exponential is monotonely increasing everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check whether the maximum of $|f'|$ is less than $1$. So take one more derivative:

$$f''(x)=-2Be^{-Bx^2}+4B^2x^2e^{-Bx^2}.$$

This is zero if and only if $4B^2x^2-2B=0$, i.e. $x^2=1/(2B)$. At these points you have $|f'(x)|=2^{1/2} B^{1/2} e^{-1/2}$. You can check that these must be the points where $|f'|$ is largest since $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$. It is clear that this grows without bound as a function of $B$, so $e^{-Bx^2}$ cannot be a contraction for all $B$.

Comment: You are wrong on the second differentiation and also why do you even look on the second derivative?

Comment: @mathreadler I am attempting to maximize $|f'|$. Also I had a typo in the first line that I had corrected in the rest of the exposition.

Comment: I think he means contraction as in |f(x)| < |x|, i.e. operator norm $\leq 1$

Comment: Mathreadler, I don't mean that when I say contraction. I talked about that in a previous comment.

Comment: @Ian I understand your point. The problem is that I need this result for ALL $B>0$. I must say that maybe what I've claimed is not true (that's why I've said "Is the function... a contraction?")

Comment: @Devilathor I didn't finish the problem. The maximum of $|f'|$ is $2^{3/2} B^{3/2} e^{-2B^2}$. You now need to maximize this and show that it is less than $1$. This problem is of a similar character to the previous optimization problem.

Comment: I'm trying to solve an exercise about roots of the function $x+e^{-Bx^2}cos(x)$ so I translated that into the language of fixed point. In order to use the Bannach Fixed Point Theorem, It suffices to show that $e^{-Bx^2}$ is a contraction

Comment: @Ian. Wouldn't this process lead to an "infinite" chain of optimizations?

Comment: @Devilathor No, once you've optimized over both variables you have just a number, not a function. Wolfram Alpha tells me this number happens to be $\left ( \frac{3}{2e} \right )^{3/4} \approx 0.64$, and is attained at $B=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}{2} \approx 0.61$.

Comment: @Ian. Of course. I don't know what was I thinking. I'm trying your suggestion but I couldn't maximize that function by hand.

Comment: @Ian. So, according that data, the function is a contraction indeed

Comment: @Devilathor Correct. Note that your problem is harder than you might think. $x+e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)=0$ if and only if $-e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)=x$, so you actually need to show that $-e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)$ is a contraction. And this function is actually *not* always a contraction, so your problem is somewhat more difficult. (Cf. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+d%2Fdx+e^%28-x^2%29+cos%28x%29 ) You can still use the Banach Fixed Point Theorem in this context, but you need to choose an appropriate compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ where your function really is a contraction ($[0,1]$ is fine).

Comment: @Ian I noted that, but $-e^{-Bx^2}\mbox{cos}(x)$ will be a contraction if $-e^{-Bx^2}$ is, isn't that right?

Comment: @Devilathor Not globally. The first product rule term, where the derivative hits the exponential, will be less than $1$ in magnitude. But the other term, where the derivative hits the cosine, may be big enough to push the whole thing larger than $1$ in magnitude. My Wolfram Alpha link above shows that this actually does happen when $B=1$ at $x \approx -0.6$.

Comment: I thought in restricting the domain too, but the exercise asks to prove that there is ONLY ONE root over all reals. I think that all this discussion shows that using Bannach Fixed Point Theorem is not the way to attack this problem. However, that's what occurred to me and I can't see any other way to solve it.

Comment: @Devilathor Ultimately it boils down to the Banach fixed point theorem, but you need to be sure that there aren't any roots *outside* your compact set. But this isn't too bad. There can't be any roots outside $[-1,1]$, because $|e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)| \leq 1$. There can't be any roots in $[-1,0]$ either, because $e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)>0$ on $[-1,1]$. So if there is a root, it is in $[0,1]$. Now you need to shrink the domain a little bit more (because the derivative is too big near x=0.59) to get it to be a contraction.

Comment: @Devilathor You also, unfortunately, must show that it maps the restricted domain into itself, which will probably not be a trivial matter.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is a contraction with rank $\lambda <1$. In particular, we must
have $|f'(x)| \le \lambda$ for all $x$, or
equivalently
${2B|x| \over e^{B x^2}}  \le \lambda$ for all $x$.

If we pick $B> ({e \over 2})^2$, then
$f'(-{1 \over \sqrt{B}}) = { 2 \sqrt{B} \over e} > 1$.

More specifically, let $B=e^2$, then $f'(-{1 \over e}) = 2$.

Comment: So your point is that the derivative cannot be bounded by 1 for all $B>0$?

Comment: @Devilathor: Yes, for sufficiently large $B$, $f$ is not a contraction. To be more specific, if you choose $B=e^2$, then $f'(-e^{-1}) = 2$.

Comment: Did you read the discussion of Ian's answer? There, it seems that what you say is not true...

Comment: Well, just do the computation in my previous comment.

Comment: ...Hm, one of us has made an error, and I am not sure which...

Comment: I didn't want to offend. I did the computations and indeed, what you say is true. So yes. there's a mistake around...

Comment: No, I think I did, I'm just not sure what it is. At any rate, Devilathor has actually reduced his original problem to a problem which is not equivalent to his original problem. I would propose that Devilathor open another question to deal with his original problem about finding roots of $x+e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)$, i.e. fixed points of $-e^{-Bx^2} \cos(x)$.

Comment: Indeed it seems I did make a mistake: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+2xye^%28-yx^2%29%2Cy%3E0 My technique works, I think I just made an algebraic mistake. I've edited my answer to remove the part where it says it is a contraction. My comments on my answer will remain problematic...

Comment: @Devilathor: I think my computation is correct.

Comment: I found my mistake: I turned $4B^2x^2-2B=0$ into $x^2=2B$ instead of $x^2=1/(2B)$.

Comment: I posted my original problem as a question by itself: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182748/show-that-xe-bx2-mboxcosx-has-only-one-root-over-all-reals-b0 I hope some of you can help me. Ian, your answer was very important, of course, you get the accepted one! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ian: 2B or not 2B?

Comment: @copper.hat Nice one!!

Comment: Hmmm, strange the way this works...